# Send and Receive File Descriptors through LIBUV Pipe

Tags: c++, ipc, file-descriptor, unix-socket, libuv

I have to send file descriptors of some shared memory buffers from one process to another. I'm able to transfer the fds directly over UNIX Domain Sockets as below:

Send FDs:

```
static void send_fds(int socket, int* fds, int n)  // send fd by socket
{
  struct msghdr msg = {0};
  struct cmsghdr* cmsg;
  char buf[CMSG_SPACE(n * sizeof(int))], dup[256];
  memset(buf, '\0', sizeof(buf));
  struct iovec io = {.iov_base = &dup, .iov_len = sizeof(dup)};

  msg.msg_iov = &io;
  msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
  msg.msg_control = buf;
  msg.msg_controllen = sizeof(buf);

  cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg);
  cmsg->cmsg_level = SOL_SOCKET;
  cmsg->cmsg_type = SCM_RIGHTS;
  cmsg->cmsg_len = CMSG_LEN(n * sizeof(int));

  memcpy((int*)CMSG_DATA(cmsg), fds, n * sizeof(int));

  if (sendmsg(socket, &msg, 0) < 0)
    printf("Failed to send message\n");
}
```

Receive FDs:

```
static int* recv_fds(int socket, int n) {
  int* fds = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
  struct msghdr msg = {0};
  struct cmsghdr* cmsg;
  char buf[CMSG_SPACE(n * sizeof(int))], dup[256];
  memset(buf, '\0', sizeof(buf));
  struct iovec io = {.iov_base = &dup, .iov_len = sizeof(dup)};

  msg.msg_iov = &io;
  msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
  msg.msg_control = buf;
  msg.msg_controllen = sizeof(buf);

  if (recvmsg(socket, &msg, 0) < 0)
    printf("Failed to receive message\n");

  cmsg = CMSG_FIRSTHDR(&msg);

  memcpy(fds, (int*)CMSG_DATA(cmsg), n * sizeof(int));

  return fds;
}
```

But when i use domain sockets through abstraction `libuv_pipe_t` provided by `libuv`, I was not able to transfer the fds. Does `libuv` provides any way to transfer file descriptors between server pipe and client pipe ? If yes how to send and receive fds exactly ?

uv_pipe_t server:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <uv.h>

#define SOCKET_NAME "socket_name"

void alloc_buffer(uv_handle_t* handle, size_t suggested_size, uv_buf_t* buf) {
  static char buffer[1024];
  buf->base = buffer;
  buf->len = sizeof(buffer);
}

void read_cb(uv_stream_t* stream, ssize_t nread, const uv_buf_t* buf) {
  if (nread < 0) {
    uv_stop(stream->loop);
    uv_close((uv_handle_t*)stream, NULL);
  }
  printf("message received : %s\n", buf->base);
}

static void connection_cb(uv_stream_t* server, int status) {
  printf("new connection recevied\n");
  int r;
  uv_pipe_t connection;
  r = uv_pipe_init(server->loop, &connection, 0);
  assert(r == 0);
  r = uv_accept(server, (uv_stream_t*)&connection);
  assert(r == 0);

  r = uv_read_start((uv_stream_t*)&connection, alloc_buffer, read_cb);
  assert(r == 0);
}

int main() {
  uv_pipe_t p;
  int r;

  r = uv_pipe_init(uv_default_loop(), &p, 0);
  assert(r == 0);

  unlink(SOCKET_NAME);
  r = uv_pipe_bind(&p, SOCKET_NAME);
  assert(r == 0);

  r = uv_listen((uv_stream_t*)&p, 128, connection_cb);
  assert(r == 0);

  printf("listening...\n");
  uv_run(uv_default_loop(), UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
  uv_loop_close(uv_default_loop());
}
```

uv_pipe_t client:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <memory.h>

#include <uv.h>

#define SOCKET_NAME "socket_name"

static void connect_cb(uv_connect_t* connect_req, int status) {
  printf("connected!");

  // send file descriptor
  int fds[2];
  fds[0] = fileno(fopen("fd_test_0.txt", "w"));
  fds[1] = fileno(fopen("fd_test_1.txt", "w"));
  
  // how to send "fds" array to server ?
}

int main() {
  uv_pipe_t p;
  uv_connect_t conn_req;
  int r;
  r = uv_pipe_init(uv_default_loop(), &p, 0);
  assert(r == 0);

  uv_pipe_connect(&conn_req, &p, SOCKET_NAME, connect_cb);

  uv_run(uv_default_loop(), UV_RUN_DEFAULT);
  uv_loop_close(uv_default_loop());
}
```

this [example](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/v1.x/test/test-pipe-sendmsg.c) shows how to transfer pipe handles over pipes but it's doesn't completely solve my problem.

Any help is appreciated !!!

Answer (score 0):

It is explained here in libuv docs: http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/guide/processes.html#sending-file-descriptors-over-pipes

You need to:

- set ipc parameter to 1 in `uv_pipe_init` on both sides
- on client use `uv_write2` to send file descriptor
- accept it on server through `uv_accept`, then take actual transferred fd number from `uv_stream_t`
  accept parameter with `uv_fileno`.

But doc says also:

> libuv only supports sending TCP sockets or other pipes over pipes for now.

So it may not work with your memory buffer file descriptor.